# Make a label appear under the entry box when the value in the entry box is > 8 in real time (xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fluentvalidation

I've read about triggers/behaviors and it only seems to change the current entry box properties.

But in my case, i want to make a label appear under my entry box if the value is >8 in REAL TIME.

For my others validation i am using Fluent Validation and the validation is done when the user click the save button BUT here this is not what i want to do since the >8 is only a warning and can be saved.

So i have to find a way to display the warning as soon as the user entered a number >8 in the entry box.

Is there a way to do this in xamarin.forms ? Also, maybe there's a way to do this with FluentValidation but not sure.

Thanks.

**Edit trying to implement with TextChanged**

**xaml**

```
<control:MaskedEntry Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Mask="XX:XX:XX" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}" TextChanged="DurationIs8"></control:MaskedEntry>

                <Label x:Name="errorMessage" Text="Greater than 8" IsVisible="False" ></Label>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
private void DurationIs8(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entryText = ((Entry)sender).Text;

    var value = Helper.GetDuration(entryText);

    if(value.TotalHours > 8)
    {
        errorMessage.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

**The GetDuration method to convert the entry box to hours**

```
public static TimeSpan GetDuration(string duration)
{
    var value = duration.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    var datetime = new TimeSpan(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
    return datetime;
}
```

Comment: just use the Entry's TextChanged event

Comment: If you are using Bindings you can bind string variable to the entry and boolean variable to the label, then in the setter of the string variable you can raise OnPropertyChanged() to update the boolean variable, hence updating the visibility of the label at real time. this vid might illustrate the idea https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Introduction-to-MVVM

Comment: @Jason i tried to implement ( see the edit ) but obviously there's something that i am doing wrong because i get an index out of bound when i get the value. Any recommendation on how to do this ? thanks

Comment: You are assuming that value will always have a length of 3

Comment: @Jason is there a way for me to tell the TextChanged event to wait until i have 8 characters because i have a masked entry which is a duration and the first two digits are the hours that i need to check but right now. But if i could wait for the entry box to be completed i think this would work. I tried to put this condition : if ( ((Entry)sender).Text.Length ==8) but the event is always fired as soon as the first number is entered

Comment: yes add some basic checks to your values - see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void DurationIs8(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entryText = ((Entry)sender).Text;

    if (entryText == null || entryText.Length < 8) return;

    var value = Helper.GetDuration(entryText);

    if(value != null && value.TotalHours > 8)
    {
        errorMessage.IsVisible = true;
    }
}

public static TimeSpan GetDuration(string duration)
{
    var value = duration.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

    if (value.Length < 3) return TimeSpan.Zero;

    var datetime = new TimeSpan(value[0], value[1], value[2]);

    return datetime;
}
```